# Xml comment <example> reference generic

Tags: c#, xml-comments

I'm trying to make some examples for a method but I just can't make it work. The generic parameters are never highlighted. What's the correct syntax?

```
/// <summary>
/// <example>
/// Example:
/// <code>
/// <see cref="Dictionary{int, object}"/> map = list.CreateMap(x => object.Field)
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// </summary>
public Dictionary<TU, T> CreateMap<TU>(Func<T, TU> fieldSelector)
{
}
```

Comment: You have some errors in your function - missing type paramete `T` and missing a notnull constraint:   `public Dictionary<TU, T> CreateMap<TU, T>(Func<T, TU> fieldSelector) where TU:  notnull`